# Waiting for database information before displaying list

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a dropdown list in a fragment that I access by referencing a ViewModel I initialize in the main activity, said ViewModel retrieving data from a mySQL database using Volley. This normally works as almost always the data has been successfully retrieved by the time the user opens the fragment requiring it, however, if I update the database and refresh my ViewModel's contents this is almost never the case (upon update I immediately return to the fragment where I need the data)

what I'd like is to be able to show a loading prompt until confirmation of successful retrieval of the data, but all resources I can find on this use the now deprecated AsyncTask, so I'm not sure how best to approach this.

Comment: use live data. while it has no data, show loading. you can use different states to show errors, loading or success

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using MutableLiveData so this would essentially just comprise adding an observer in the fragment in question and setting a load prompt while the data is empty?

Comment: should work, you can create an additional live data to show the state of your view as another option, something which has a state of `success/loading/error`, then based on this you can show different things on your view. once you start the load, set the state to loading, show loading on your view, if success/error, show or hide relevant info

Comment: @a_local_nobody Great idea, thanks so much! really helped me here